# OldVersion="0.0.0.0-x.x.x.x" is not accepting in WebConfig file

Tags: c#, web-config, config, assemblyversions

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="assembly" publicKeyToken="b87ed1f09d48c01" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-x.x.x.x" newVersion="x.x.x.x" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I have given this in my web config file to accept the range of versions but I am getting below exception.

```
 Application Configuration file "Web.config" is invalid. There was a problem parsing the oldVersion attribute. Input string was not in a correct format.
```